# StreamWriter trouble writing doubles to .txt file (C++)

Tags: io, c++-cli, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

I'm trying to write some double values to a text file the user creates via a SaveFileDialog, but everytime I do a streamWriterVariable->Write(someDoubleVariable), I instead see some kind of weird ASCII character in the text file where the double should be (music note, |, copyright symbol, etc). I'm opening the file with notepad if it's that of any significance. A basic outline of my code:

```
SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
saveFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
saveFileDialog1->Title = "Save File Here";
saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
if (saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
 FileInfo ^fleTest = gcnew FileInfo(saveFileDialog1->FileName);
 StreamWriter ^sWriter = fleTest->CreateText();
 sWriter->AutoFlush = true;
 double test = 5.635; //Some arbitrary double I made up for test purposes
 sWriter->Write(test);
 sWriter->Flush();
 sWriter->Close();
}
```

---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the encoding explicitly?

```
StreamWriter^ sWriter = gcnew StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1->FileName, false, System::Text::Encoding::ASCII);
```

Comment: So enconding explicitly hasn't fully solved the problem but it's offered a kind of solution: when I encode explicitly and write only do writeLine(double), it works. If I do write(double) followed by any write("string") it messes up, in addition to any write(string) followed by a write(double). Needless to say though your advice has led me to a solution so thank you!

For future reference I had two errors when trying your declaration: one, it claimed that ANSI wasn't an encoder type, and two, it said that it didn't expect a bool value for the 2nd spot in the parameter. Thanks though!

Comment: Oops I meant System::Text::Encoding::ASCII. Have you tried to open the resulting file with an advanced text editor like Notepad++? Moreover is the file always created from scratch, ie deleted before any new writes?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided does exactly what you ask it to, that is to write a double to the file in the internal computer format. What you most likely want it to write out the textual representation of the double.

In other words you should try `sWriter->Write(test.ToString())` or some variation over this, to get the textual version of your double. This also applies to bool and most other variable representation.